# this question is related to operation research .( facility location problem)

Tags: integer-programming, operations-research

This is a conceptual facility location problem. I want advice on how one would approach it.

- We have 20 stands, each plotted on a 2d map. Each stand demands a certain # of
  apples per year.
- We are trying to place apple factories that can supply every stand’s demand.

A. Factory Constraints:

- a. Any factory must supply between 6,000 and 10,000 apples
- b. The    factory cannot supply more than 200km away.
- Minimize the number of    factories built.

i have included what i have done so far.

Steps

- First formulate a mathematical approach to find a distance from each
  factory to each location. (initially begin with 25 factories)
- Fill the demand matrix using the given values.
- Use a indicator variable called yi to calculate the total supply from i th factory. Here yi =1 if we assign the i th factory to any of the location and otherwise yi=0.
- Calculate the respective supplies using equation (2).
- Formulate the mathematical model using relevant constraints.
- Solve it using computer pregame.

**i just want to know whether these steps are correct or not. Also i am very appreciate if someone can provide me the mathematical formulation.**

Comment: Do you start out with a fixed set of possible factory locations, or can you put a factory anywhere on the map?

Comment: we can start with any number of factories and yes we can place the factories anywhere on the map such that it satisfies the distance constraints.

Comment: Assuming you have a (finite) set of discrete map points where a factory could go, you might want to search for the "warehouse location problem". It's a standard OR/logistics problem, well documented, and there is no mathematical difference between serving stands from warehouses and serving them from factories.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time .